# Detect the most used color in image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect lane lines in a video while I am driving. I reached the step where Canny Edge detection is applied on the region of interest. The region of interest contains only the white line, yellow line and the street (in gray color). Now, I need to mask any other color inside the region of interest because the gray color sometimes interrupt the other color in the edge detection. Then, when we apply the Hough Lines on the yellow and white lines, the detection is not accurate.

So, can how can I apply another mask on the image to leave the yellow and white parts alone?

I am using OpenCV for computer vision and image processing functions with Python.

Comment: You can use `cv2.inRange()` and pass a tuple of HSV values

Comment: Canny detection when looking for road lines is too simplistic.  Let's think about it for a second:  depending on the time of day, those line colors are going to look slightly different to the camera.  Also, what if it's raining or foggy?  What if you have lines on the side of a fence across the street at a T intersection?

Typically deep learning is used for detection tasks like this for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code making use of PIL and Scipy's cluster package.

```
import struct
import Image
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import scipy.cluster

NUM_CLUSTERS = 5

print 'reading image'
im = Image.open('image.jpg')
im = im.resize((150, 150))      # optional, to reduce time
ar = np.asarray(im)
shape = ar.shape
ar = ar.reshape(scipy.product(shape[:2]), shape[2]).astype(float)

print 'finding clusters'
codes, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(ar, NUM_CLUSTERS)
print 'cluster centres:\n', codes

vecs, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.vq(ar, codes)         # assign codes
counts, bins = scipy.histogram(vecs, len(codes))    # count occurrences

index_max = scipy.argmax(counts)                    # find most frequent
peak = codes[index_max]
colour = ''.join(chr(int(c)) for c in peak).encode('hex')
print 'most frequent is %s (#%s)' % (peak, colour)
```